# Which logging framework my Flink application is using?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, apache-flink, logback

My Flink logs are not showing up anywhere.  So I'm reading on how to resolve this.
I have read a couples of articles on how to change log levels in flink/conf files to  help me resolve this.

But then I read about flink having two logging framework options. They are :
Log4j & logback.

So now how do I determine which framework my Flink application is using?

Comment: "By default, Log4j 2 is used as the underlying logging framework." You can find it on official docs [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/advanced/logging/)